# Can I use Geronimo instead of Apache Tomcat for deploying?

Tags: webmathematica, deployment

I am using Apache Tomcat for deploying Web-Applications. I want to deploy Apps in Geronimo (also built by Apache), because it's open source and provides more features (clustering, JMS, Application Server) than Tomcat.

Before installing Geronimo, I'd like to know if `webMathematica` will work with Geronimo.

Has anybody tried this?

Thanks

---

@All, I placed my Application folder under web-apps folder of `Apache Geronimo`,it's working great.But here I faced one problem.

I made `.war` file of my Application and I tried to deploy `.war` file into `Apache Geronimo`,it shows `deployed successfully`.

I open my application in browser,it's not working.I will figure out.finally webMathematica applications are working in `Apache Geronimo`.

Answer (score 5):

"Any engine compatible with Servlet 2.4 or later, such as Apache Tomcat"

- http://www.wolfram.com/products/webmathematica/technology/?tab=Specifications

I really don't know much about Geronimo, but it [seems to support servlet 2.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Geronimo) (via Tomcat.)